# Getting error while running the pg_basebackup through PGBOUNCER

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, pgbouncer

We are using PGBOUNCER (connection pool mechanisam). PGBOUNCER uses port 5433.

Postgres database port number is 6433. By using port 5433 PGBOUNCER is connecting to the Postgres database on port 6433.

Now PGBOUNCER is establishing the connections properly, but when I try to run `pg_basebackup` through port 5433 (PGBOUNCER port), we are receiving the below error. Please guide me.

```
/opt/postgres/9.2/bin/pg_basebackup -p 5433 -U postgres -P -v -x --format=tar --gzip --compress=1 --pgdata=- -D /opt/rao

pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: ERROR:  Unsupported startup parameter: replication
```

Answer (score 2):

pgBouncer cannot speak the [replication protocol](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/protocol-replication.html), so you cannot run `pg_basebackup` through it.

It doesn't make sense to speak the replication protocol through a connection pooler anyway, because replication connections tend to be long lived, and there are not too many of them. So pooling makes no sense.

Connect to PostgreSQL directly to run your backup.

Needless to say, but it is a very bad idea to be running PostgreSQL 9.2 today.

Comment: Thanks for the update. PostgreSQL up gradation plan is there in our road-map.